# Using 2 terminal band gap voltage reference

Tags: voltage, reference

Specifically, LM385.
Am I correct in assuming that a resistor is chosen to pass a current between 50uA to 10mA through the device from the PSU, and the reference voltage appears across the terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume correctly - you decide on the voltage regulation point (volts), subtract that from your power supply voltage and use the difference voltage and a resistor to set the operating current.

Take into account how much current flows through the other resistors too (if using them): -

[image]

Comment: BTW, are these run forward biased, as opposed to a zener?

Comment: They use what is known as a band-gap reference which is a bunch of transistors and shouldn't really be compared with a zener - you can run a zener in forward mode and it performs like a diode but if you reversed the supply on the LM385 you could destroy it.